# While reading the excel data into Selenium I'm trying to get the Date and Year values as Integers from strings by parsing them. Initially I split them

Tags: java

They don't get parsed instead an error is seen as below: For input string: "5"

Please help me how to parse them and please tell me if I'm doing it wrong anywhere ?

Code:

```
String day = cellValue.split("-")[0];
int intDay = Integer.parseInt(day);
```

Excel data:

```
"5-Feb-2000"
```

Comment: You can parse the `String` with a `DateTimeFormatter`, receive a `LocalDate` as result and finally access the values there.

Comment: Hi @deHaar, thanks for the suggestion. Actually it's a birthday field where it has 3 different fields for date, month, year. So I want to set the birthday in the past. Could you please tell me how this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Plain `java.time`…

A simple possibility of getting the desired values is to parse the `String` with a `DateTimeFormatter` capable of the format and accessing the values directly in the resulting `LocalDate`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // input value
    String input = "5-Feb-2000";
    // the DateTimeFormatter to be used as a parser
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
    // use the parser to get a LocalDate from the input String
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(input, dtf);
    // print its toString() (implicitly)
    System.out.println(localDate);
    // print the day of month
    System.out.println("day of month:  " + localDate.getDayOfMonth());
    // print the month of year
    System.out.println("month of year: " + localDate.getMonthValue());
    // print the year
    System.out.println("year:          " + localDate.getYear());
}
```

Output:

```
2000-02-05
day of month:  5
month of year: 2
year:          2000
```

If you have a *birthday field where it has 3 different fields for date, month, year*, you can just use the methods that are called in the last three print statements of my example code. Take their values and insert them where desired…

Comment: This is so clear for me. Thanks for the lot of help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse String value to Date object and Date object to LocateDate. LocalDate object contains field for date, month, year ...

```
        String cellValue ="5-Feb-2000";
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        
        Date parsedDate= fmt.parse(cellValue);
        System.out.println(parsedDate);
        LocalDate localDate = parsedDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        
        System.out.println("Date= "+localDate.getDayOfMonth()+"  Month = "+localDate.getMonthValue());
```

Comment: glad to know it worked for you.  upvote is another way to say thanks :)